# Whats the meaning of gcc/g++ error 'implicitly-declared' constructor is 'deprecated'?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, deprecation-warning

I am trying to chase down errors coming out of upgrading my build system OS and gcc version with it to 9. I can demonstrate it with the following code.

```
class Cl {
        private:
                float f;
        public:
        constexpr float GetF() const { return f; }
        Cl& operator=(const Cl& other) {
                f = other.GetF();
                return *this;
        }
        Cl& operator=(const float& other) {
                this->f = other;
                return *this;
        }
        explicit constexpr Cl(const float& val) : f(val) {}
};

struct Sl {
        float x, y;
        Cl lcl;
        constexpr Sl(const float &init_x, const float &init_y, const Cl &cl) : x(init_x), y(init_y), lcl(cl) {}

};

typedef struct Sl sdata;

int main()
{
        const float fx = 30.30;
        Cl c1(fx);
        sdata s1(0, 0.0, c1);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
preetam@preetam-Precision-M4800 ~ $ g++-9 -Werror=deprecated-copy dp_test.cc 
dp_test.cc: In constructor ‘constexpr Sl::Sl(const float&, const float&, const Cl&)’:
dp_test.cc:22:101: error: implicitly-declared ‘constexpr Cl::Cl(const Cl&)’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-copy]
   22 |  constexpr Sl(const float &init_x, const float &init_y, const Cl &cl) : x(init_x), y(init_y), lcl(cl) {}
      |                                                                                                     ^
dp_test.cc:8:6: note: because ‘Cl’ has user-provided ‘Cl& Cl::operator=(const Cl&)’
    8 |  Cl& operator=(const Cl& other) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors`
```

Whats is the meaning of the error ?

I tried adding the following to Cl as suggested here:

```
constexpr Cl(const Cl& other) {
    f = other.GetF();
}
```

It resulted in the error:

```
preetam@preetam-Precision-M4800 ~ $ g++-9 -Werror=deprecated-copy dp_test.cc 
dp_test.cc: In copy constructor ‘constexpr Cl::Cl(const Cl&)’:
dp_test.cc:10:9: error: member ‘Cl::f’ must be initialized by mem-initializer in ‘constexpr’ constructor
   10 |         }
      |         ^
dp_test.cc:5:9: note: declared here
    5 |   float f;
      |         ^
```

Finally Fixed with the following copy constructor:

```
constexpr Cl(const Cl& other) : f(other.f) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a copy-constructor for `lcl(cl)` although you didn't define one but you defined a user-defined assignment operator. You can fix it by adding a user-defined constructor:

```
class Cl {
        private:
                float f;
        public:
        constexpr float GetF() const { return f; }
        constexpr Cl(const Cl& other) : f(other.f) { }
        Cl& operator=(const Cl& other) {
                f = other.GetF();
                return *this;
        }
        Cl& operator=(const float& other) {
                this->f = other;
                return *this;
        }
        explicit constexpr Cl(const float& val) : f(val) {}
};

struct Sl {
        float x, y;
        Cl lcl;
        constexpr Sl(const float &init_x, const float &init_y, const Cl &cl) : x(init_x), y(init_y), lcl(cl) {}

};

typedef struct Sl sdata;

int main()
{
        const float fx = 30.30;
        Cl c1(fx);
        sdata s1(0, 0.0, c1);
        return 0;
}
```

Nitpick: *"Whats is the meaning of the error ?"* It's not an error but a warning. The project can be compiled and should run as expected but of course, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: The project doesn't compile because its build flags treat this as error. Anyways, I still get an error

dp_test.cc: In copy constructor ‘constexpr Cl::Cl(const Cl&)’:
dp_test.cc:10:9: error: member ‘Cl::f’ must be initialized by mem-initializer in ‘constexpr’ constructor
   10 |         }
      |         ^
dp_test.cc:5:9: note: declared here
    5 |   float f;
      |         ^

Comment: @preetam Can't reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wVyTEaLaGpS30tmk Do you use a member initializer list in the constructor?

Comment: The copy constructor is different from what you proposed in the code.

Comment: thank you for the demo code. I understand better with examples than specs.

Answer (score 2):

The `lcl` member of the `Sl` struct is initialised in the constructor of `Sl`.
This initialisation implies the usage of the copy constructor.

However, as stated by the message of the compiler, if we provide our own version of the copy-assign operator, this certainly means that there is something subtle in such a copy operation, then the copy-constructor should have probably been explicitly provided too.

If no copy-assign operator is provided, then the default one is considered as suitable, and the default copy-constructor is probably suitable too.

Note that you should always consider the [rule of five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five).